# My sqlite3 if-else query in Flask application isn't returning the results I want

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

application.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask , render_template, request
import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/salary", methods = ["POST"])
def salar():
    name = request.form.get("employeee_name")
    price = request.form.get("pay")
    with sql.connect('database.db') as conn:
        c=conn.cursor()
    if c.execute('SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_name=name').fetchone() is None:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO employees(employee_name,basicpayment) VALUES (?,?)',(name,price))
        conn.commit()
        return render_template("success.html", name=name)
    else: 
        return render_template("already.html")  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Database Creation

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE employees(employee_name TEXT,basicpayment INT)')
conn.close()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</body>
<title>MY SALARY</title>
<body>
    <form action="{{url_for('salar')}}" method ="POST">
        <input type="text" name="employeee_name" placeholder="Enter employee name here.....">
        <input type="number" name="pay" placeholder="Enter pay of employee">
        <button>SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>EMPLOYEE ADDED TO DATABASE</head>
<BODY>
    <P>
        {{name}}, has been added to database!
        <a href="{{url_for('index')}}">MAKE ANOTHER ENTRY TO THE DATABASE</a>
    </P>
</BODY>
</html>
```

already.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>THIS EMPLOYEE ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <P>
        {{name}}, already exists in the database!
        <a href="{{url_for('index')}}">MAKE ANOTHER ENTRY TO THE DATABASE</a>
    </P>
</BODY>
</html>
```

I have been deleting the database and creating it again because of the "wrong" error messages. Sometimes it says table isn't created and sometimes it can't find the column name.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to create `cursor()` object

Here is the correct code to connect:

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c=conn.cursor() # add this
c.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists employees(employee_name TEXT,basicpayment INT)')
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I am a beginner and really thanks for helping

Comment: I tried executing but it doesnt work. Still showing name coloumn doesn;t exist.

Comment: Try this one ```if c.execute('SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_name=%s'%name).fetchone() is None:```

Comment: Still I am unable to do....but thanks a lot for your help....appreciated it a lot

Answer (score 1):

This `SELECT employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_name=name` would give a "can't find column name" message because `employees` has not column called `name`. Here is info from the [sqlite3 python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) on how to use parameter substitution:

> use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.

The doc gives many examples.

Comment: I tried executing but it doesnt work. Still showing name coloumn doesn;t exist

Comment: You changed the SELECT query? To what?